# confused on setting javascript object property value

Tags: javascript

I am creating an object

```
var testobj=function(x)
{
    var b,c;
    var a=x;
    var init=function(d,e,f)
    {
        a=d;
        b=e;
        c=f;
    };
    return{
        init:init,
        b:function(){
        return b;
        },
        a:a,
        c:c   
    }
};
//here some test of the object
var instobj=new testobj(4);
instobj.init(1,2,3);
alert(instobj.a);  //display 4
alert(instobj.b()); //display 2
alert(instobj.c); //display nothing
```

I don't understand why I can't get value of 'c' by simply reference to it, instead, I need to use a function to return that value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: It doesn't display nothing, it displays "undefined" because the value of `c` is undefined. Also note that `instobj.a` isn't working as I suspect you wanted it to because it's value is still `4`.

Comment: JavaScript has assign-by-value. Assigning a new value to `c` later on in the `init` function doesn't magically change the value of the property of the object.

Comment: You don't get an *instance* back from the `new testobj(4)` expression because you're returning an anonymous object, hence defeating the purpose of a constructor function.

Comment: More on constructor functions and prototype here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What happened?*

I expected you to use the function object when you used new, but you returned an object.

```
-->return{
    init:init,
    b:function(){
    return b;
    },
    a:a,
    c:c   
}
```

Usually new isn't used when an object is being returned. When this happens, the context of the function object is lost, as a result, this is what the returned object's init function looks like

```
function(d,e,f)
{
    a=d;
    b=e;
    c=f;
};
```

with literally no reference to anything else. At this point you are in a global scope (unless bind was used which is a different issue) causing a,b, and c to now be defined globally (assuming strict is not being used). So what this accomplishes is to create 3 global variables and then assign them to the values.

As a result, this is what ends up happening in your calls at the very end.

You first start by assigning the three global variables a,b, and c to 1,2, and 3

```
instobj.init(1,2,3);
```

Next, you alert the value of a, which was still referenced by your returned object, and took a value from the constructor of 4. As a result 4 is alerted

```
alert(instobj.a);  //display 4 (because that came from the constructor)
```

In the following line, you reference a function which has no context and as a result is referencing global scope. The variable it returns is the global variable `b`, set above with init to 2

```
alert(instobj.b()); //display 2 (this returned b, a global variable)
```

The last call is to c. However, c is still referencing the original function object's variable c, and that was only declared once but never assigned to. (remember? `var b,c;`. If this were `var a,c=-1;` then the following code would alert -1).

```
alert(instobj.c); //display nothing (undefined from var b,c;)
```

*What could be changed?*

Usually a prototypal approach is taken in javascript. This means you set up a constructor, define some prototype functions that each instance will use, and then new up instances of those. For your testobj, that would look like this:

```
function Test(x){
 this.a = x;
 this.b = undefined;
 this.c = undefined;
}
Test.prototype.init = function(d,e,f){
 this.a = d;
 this.b = e;
 this.c = f;
};
```

When new is used, `this` refers to the instance of the function object. Later, when referencing the variable the instantiation was assigned to, the `.` property name may be used to reference `this.` property values.

Also when new is used, functions attached to the prototype are included in the instantiated object. Their scope is the same `this` as described above, and the property references will be the same as well.

As a result, you may access your test object like this:

```
var testobj = new Test(4);
testobj.init(1,2,3);
alert(testobj.a);//1
alert(testobj.b);//2
alert(testobj.c);//3
```

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/58T5j/)***

<sub>[Link to top of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896150/1026459)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you are generating properties for objects you should be using `this`, for example:

```
function TestObj () {
    this.c = 3;
    this.b = function (number) {
        alert(number);
    };

    return this;
}

var instance = new TestObj();
alert(instance.c);
instance.b(4);
```

Read more about [OOP in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)